# Simple name scraper from folder

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read multiple text files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668064/read-multiple-text-files-in-a-folder)

I have a folder with files, for example: 
123.psd
12345.psd
123456.psd
etc, i want to scrape all the names inside the folder into a TXT file
how do i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Dim filesNames = From path In IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Temp")
                 Select IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Filenames.txt", filesNames)
```

Edit: Here's a version that works also in .NET 3.5:

```
Dim filesNames = From path In IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("C:\Temp")
         Select IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Filenames.txt", filesNames.ToArray)
```

and this works even in .NET 2:

```
Dim filesNames = IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("C:\Temp")
Dim fileNamesWithoutExtension(filesNames.Length - 1) As String
For i = 0 To filesNames.Length - 1
    fileNamesWithoutExtension(i) = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filesNames(i))
Next
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Filenames.txt", fileNamesWithoutExtension)
```

Comment: @JonEgerton: The `_`(line continuation) is unnecessary in VB.NET 4.

Comment: Interesting - Have been working in VS2008 in VB.Net, so still stuck with them. Was just checking on my work remote connection that I hadn't gone mad!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm getting few errors now:

'Select Case' must end with a matching 'End Select'.
Name 'path' is not declared.
Statments and labels are not valid between 'Select Case' and first 'Case'.

Comment: @JasonBrill: What framework version are you using?

Comment: Worked! Thank You so much Tim!