# replace text multiple file vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want multiple files with a name and in a different format
I will replace some of the text

To do this, use the following command:

```
 Dim sb As New StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText("tmp\boot_root\initrd\fstab.*"))
        sb.Replace("ro,barrier", "ro,noatime,barrier")
        sb.Replace("ro,errors", "ro,noatime,errors")
```

But this does not work. I need a better command to do this

help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read multiple text files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668064/read-multiple-text-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: I saw the post
But I need to do this for different format of name ,
For example:
Format all files named fstab

Comment: The duplicate target addresses using search patterns.

Comment: So you're trying to figure out how to grab all files in a directory with names that match a given pattern?

Comment: Yes I want to do all the files in a folder
The same name but different format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all files matching a pattern in a given directory use Directory.Getfiles(path, pattern). Example:

```
Dim list as String()
Dim path as String = "C:\tmp\"
Dim filename as String = "fstab"

list = Directory.GetFiles(path, filename & ".*")

For Each file As String In list
    'Logic goes here.
Next
```

Comment: thenks bro I used the following logic :  My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file).Replace("ro,barrier", "ro,noatime,barrier")  But the replacement is not done , Can you give me a better Command?

Comment: FileSystem.ReadAllText returns the contents of a file, as a string. String.Replace returns a copy of the string, with the first value replaced by the second. If you're looking to change the contents of the file you need to set some string = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file).Replace("ro,barrier", "ro,noatime,barrier"), then write that string to the file. You might want to look into streamreaders and streamwriters to help you with that. Plenty of advice on their use here on stackoverflow.